# User registration fields not being saved in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5 and have amended the default registrar a bit to use first_name and last_name instead of just name. For some reason though when the user is created the first_name and last_name fields are blank in the database. This is the code I am using:

```
public function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'discount_code' => 'max:255',
        'register_email' => 'required|email|confirmed|max:255|unique:users,email',
        'register_password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6|max:60'
    ]);
}

public function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['register_email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['register_password'])
    ]);
}
```

In the create method if I do a print_r($data) before User::create is called first_name and last_name are there but when the entry is stored to my users table in the database only the email and password get stored. Here is my table definition also:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `first_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `last_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `password` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
    `discount_code` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `remember_token` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Comment: Did you make the first_name and last_name fields mass assignable in the model?

Comment: Ahhh! Thanks that did the trick! Do you want to post a proper answer and I'll accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `first_name` and `last_name` fields need to be mass assignable in the model through the `$fillable`/`$guarded` arrays.